# Prevent SQL injection in spark SQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql, apache-spark, sql-injection

I am using spark SQL to get data from my remote MYSQL database. How do I make sure SQL injection doesnt happen as I cant seem to find a way to avoid SQL injection in spark SQl

```
spark = SparkSession.builder()
            .master("local[*]")
            .appName("testApp")
            .getOrCreate();
Dataset<Row> dbData =  spark.read().jdbc("url", table,properties);
```

I want to select columns of a table with limit with preventing sql injection.
The Query is

> Select col1,col2,col3,col4 from table limit ?,?

Is it possible in spark sql java api?

Comment: Usually, you just use parameterized queries.  The same rules apply for all languages to prevent SQL injection: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: @tadman In the example code I am selecting the entire table. I want to select specific columns with limit through apache spark ( like the query below code).I want  to know how that can be done in spark java api.?