# Safely querying using spark. sql query notation with parameters

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

This question refers to building pyspark jobs to process large data sets.  Spark offers many ways to query. Functional notation as well as SQL notation.  **This question is restricted to the Spark SQL notation/pattern.**

A common pattern is:

`df=spark.sql(f"select * from sometable where somecolumn='${somevalue}'"); #dangerous`

But the above can suffer from malformed expressions even if not from direct user input.  (Perhaps it is simply malformed data.) Ideally the following would be supported but alas it is not.

`df=spark.sql(f"select * from sometable where somecolumn=?",somevalue); #sadly does not exist`

A thought comes to mind to register a lambda function using kwargs:

```
def safeSql(query,**args):
    spark.udf.register("arg", lambda x: args[x])
    return(spark.sql(query))
     
safeSql("select arg('a'),arg('b')",a=4,b="O'Malley").show()
```

The above works perfectly. Is this the best approach?

*This should be an easy answer and I am surprised it is so elusive.*

Unfortunately, these questions/answers give wrong or incomplete answers:

- [Prevent SQL injection in spark SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48194638/prevent-sql-injection-in-spark-sql)
- [What is the preferred way to avoid SQL injections in Spark-SQL (on Hive)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29669106/what-is-the-preferred-way-to-avoid-sql-injections-in-spark-sql-on-hive)
- [Apache Spark: In SparkSql, are sql's vulnerable to Sql Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41941472/apache-spark-in-sparksql-are-sqls-vulnerable-to-sql-injection)
- [Escaping user inputs for Spark SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30062559/escaping-user-inputs-for-spark-sql)

Comment: Do you have any idea why safeSql would not work for insert statement?
Like: 
def safeSql(query,**args):
    spark.udf.register("arg", lambda x: args.get(x))
    return(spark.sql(query))



insert = "insert into testing (cola, colb, colc) VALUES (arg('a'), arg('b'), arg('c'))"


safeSql(insert, a = "AAAA", b = "BBBB", c = "CCCCC")

AnalysisException: [INVALID_INLINE_TABLE.CANNOT_EVALUATE_EXPRESSION_IN_INLINE_TABLE] Invalid inline table. Cannot evaluate the expression "arg(a)" in inline table definition.; line 1 pos 47

Answer (score 1):

Parameterized SQL is supported for [`spark.sql()` in pyspark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.SparkSession.sql.html), see the args (introduced in 3.4.0 in April 2023) and kwargs (introduced in 3.3.0 in June 2022) arguments.

Ex:

```py
a = "a'string"
bvals = ("b", "str", """compl"ex'""")
spark.sql("SELECT id FROM table WHERE col IN {b} AND col2 = {a}", b=bvals, a=a)
```

I am still looking for escaping clarification when using the `query` option when loading from jdbc and other sources in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76822857/is-there-a-way-to-use-parameterized-queries-in-pyspark-when-passing-a-query-to-l).