# Is there a way to use parameterized queries in pyspark when passing a query to load data from jdbc?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I've found the pyspark documentation which supports parameterized queries when using the [`sql` method](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.SparkSession.sql.html) but have not been able to find an equivalent for the query option when loading data through jdbc (or other formats allowing the query option).

When using the `.sql()` method:

```py
bvals = ("a", "str", """compl"ex'""")
spark.sql("SELECT id FROM table WHERE col in {b}", b=bvals)
```

When loading using the `query` option:

```py
bvals = ("a", "str", """compl"ex'""")
spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url", "jdbc:...").option(
    "query",
    f"""SELECT id FROM table WHERE col in (
        {", ".join('"'+val.replace('"', r'\"')+'"' for val in bvals)}
    )"""
).load()
```

Ideally I would like to pass these in parameterized so I don't have to escape anything. If that's not possible is there a common function in pyspark for escaping values for SQL? In the scala `Literal` class there is a [`sql` function](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/literals.scala#L476) which returns a SQL-escaped string but I don't see an equivalent in pyspark.